# JavaScript function only fires when there are 2 input boxes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have an aspx page in Visual Studio. I have a function which fires on the onkeyup.
When I have just the single control on the page, the JavaScript function is not called. When I add a second control, the JavaScript is called.

With this code, the JavaScript does not fire...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
            <input type="text" onkeyup="searchBarcode()" class="form-control" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function searchBarcode() {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this code the JavaScript fires

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="registration">Registration</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRegistration" name="registration" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="searchBarcode()" class="form-control" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function searchBarcode() {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                alert('Hello');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The first one submits the form when you hit Enter. What is `searchBarcode()` actually supposed to do? Do those controls need to be inside of a `<form>`?

Comment: Why does the first submit the form and the second call the JavaScript function? The searchBarcode function calls another function which calls some code-behind. It does need to be in a form to send the data to the code-behind.

Comment: Did you check the browser console? Because the first example works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/m1br532h/

Comment: @DanielGee "_Why does the first submit the form and the second call the JavaScript function?_" Because this is either specified in the HTML specs or the user agent thought it was logical. If it needs to be sent to the code-behind via a form, then what is the purpose of the JavaScript function? Why not just let it submit?

Comment: @Ivar, the code-behind is not for the submit. It adds the item to a list. How do I check the HTML specs?

Comment: If you want to execute the function instead of submitting the form, you can add `event.preventDefault();` to the first line of your `searchBarcode()`. Though that would render the form useless as far as I can see, so you could try to remove the form instead. But I don't have too much experience with asp.net, so maybe the removal will break other things. The HTML specs can be found [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/), though I don't think you're going to find anything useful in there.

Comment: The part of the HTML specs I was referring to in my earlier comment, is [this one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission).

Comment: @ChrisG, I see it works on the jsfiddle. Maybe the issue has to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: Inline `onkeyup` is bad practice anyway; use `addEventListener` instead and check for errors. Also, once you have the final HTML and script in the browser, Visual Studio doesn't really matter anymore.

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks for the advice. I'll update the code and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('txtBarcode').addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent)
  }
  function keyEvent(e) {
            var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                alert('Hello');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: remove this code: onkeyup="searchBarcode()"

Comment: How is this supposed to make a difference?

Comment: this is a better method for performance.

Comment: But OP wasn't asking for better performance. They are asking why the first snippet doesn't execute the JavaScript. Nothing in this answer will make a difference in that regard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing passing event to the function

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
            <input type="text" onkeyup="searchBarcode(e)" class="form-control" id="txtBarcode" name="barcode" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function searchBarcode(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `event` is [a global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) and thus doesn't need to be explicitly passed as a parameter to work. (Though it is encouraged to do so.) This wont change anything.